# How to map superclass fields from imported package with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, superclass

I want to map the fields of the superclass Property. This class is imported, so i can not modify this superclass, can not add the @Mappedsuperclass annotation to it.

Is there a way to map the superclass fields?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "properties_test")
public class PropertyRecord extends Property {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataType", referencedColumnName = "dataTypeId")
    private DataType dataType;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sourceOfData", referencedColumnName = "sourceOfDataId")
    private SourceOfData sourceOfData;
    
    private Integer price;
    
    private Integer unitPrice;

};
```

I checked the documentation but did not find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add getters/setters in the `PropertyRecord` class for the data of the `Property` class and annotate the getters. Don't forget to tell Hibernate to use property access by annotating `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on the `PropertyRecord` class.